# How to set the color of the first column of a Listview item?

Tags: android-listview, background-color

I have a `Listview` (shown in an AlertDialog) that is composed by two columns, made with a `HashMap` (got the idea somewhere here). 
Each column is a `TextView`. It works well.

Now I want to change the textcolor of the first column of a given row, but I have no idea on how to pick and set this... I googled for hours! Any clues??

This is my code (`lists` is a `SortedSet`):

```
public void showlistdesc () {
    ListView listview = new ListView(this);
    listview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    listview.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
    listview.setSelector(R.drawable.selector);

    Integer i=0, pos = 0;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;
    for (String l : lists) {
        if (l.equals(currlist)) pos = i;
        i++;
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("list", l);
        map.put("desc", getlistdesc(l, false));
        mylist.add(map);
    }

    listview.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.lists_row,
                new String[] {"list", "desc"}, new int[] {R.id.list1, R.id.desc1}));

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AveActivity.this)
            .setView(listview)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle(lists.size() + " bird lists in databases");

    final AlertDialog dial = builder.create();

    //Scrolls the listview to this position at top
    listview.setSelection(pos);

    dial.show();
}
```

Thanks!

*EDIT*

Tried to extend `SimpleAdapter` with the following code, and all I can see are solid black rows:

```
public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
private Context context;

public MySimpleAdapter(Context context,List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
        int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lists_row, null);
    }

    TextView list1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list1));
    TextView desc1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc1));

    if (v.isPressed()) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.pressed));
        list1.setTypeface(null, 1);
        list1.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.selected));
    } else {
        v.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        if (v.isSelected()) {
            list1.setTypeface(null, 1);
            list1.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.checked));
            desc1.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        } else {
            list1.setTypeface(null, 0);
            list1.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.normal));
            desc1.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.lesswhite));
        }
    }

    return v;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, essentially contained in several posts here.
What I did was to use `listview.setItemChecked(pos, true);`, something that I tried before and failed, because it showed nothing. The problem was that `LinearLayout` does not implement `Checkable`. So I implemented it (code found essentially somewhere here also) with this:

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
private boolean isChecked;

public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
    TextView list1 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.list1));
    TextView desc1 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc1));
    if (isPressed()) {
        list1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.selected));
        setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pressed));
    } else {
        setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        if (isChecked) {
            list1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.checked));
            desc1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        } else {
            list1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.normal));
            desc1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lesswhite));
        }
    }
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}

public void toggle() {
    setChecked(!isChecked);
}
}
```

And that's it. No need to use `selector`, nor to touch the adapter. To make this work, in the row `layout`, use `<com.[yourpackage].CheckableLinearLayout` instead of the usual `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have special requirement, it is no longer *simple*, you can't use `SimpleAdapter` to achieve the effect you are asking. You will have to extend `BaseAdapter` and in the `getView()` method you can do the following:

```
if (position == 0) {
    convertView.setBackground(color1);
} else {
    convertView.setBackground(color2);        
}
```

Or if what you want is a *Header*, you can use `ListView.addHeaderView()` without much hassle.

Comment: I see, that's a good reason why I failed. I don't want a header, I just want that one of the elements in the list look different to the user. I could even change the background of the whole line, or thetext color  (can I do this with a simple adapter??). I tried everything I can think of (selectors,  etc) and failed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As I said in the answer, this is a *special* requirement, which can not be achieved with a `SimpleAdapter`. Also I don't think it is good to use some kind of hack simply because you want to stick with `SimpleAdapter`. A custom adapter is nothing complex **at all**.

Comment: Yes, I understood your answer. I'll think about it, and will try to implement it. Thanks!

Comment: I extended `SimpleAdapter` as in the EDIT above, and all I can see is solid black rows. Looks way more complicated than my solution.